# put variable from get_content in array()

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

Have code that create video gallery with thumbs from Vimeo.

```
<?php
            $videos = Array("128171814", "128171814", "128171814", "128171814", "128171814", "128171814", "128171814", "128171814", "128171814", "128171814", "128171814", "128171814", "128171814", "128171814", "128171814", "128171814", "128171814", "128171814", "128171814", "128171814", "128171814", "128171814", "128171814", "128171814", "128171814", "128171814", "127958989", "126775227", "126775227", "126775227", "126775227", "126775227", "126775227", "126775227", "126775227", "126775227", "126775227", "126775227", "126775227", "126775227", "126775227", "126775227", "126775227", "126775227",);
        ?>

        <div class="video-responsive">

        <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/<?= $videos[0] ?>" width="500" height="309" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen style="display: block; margin-bottom: 10px"></iframe>

        </div>
        <div class="thumbs">
        <div>
        <?php
            foreach($videos as $video)
            {
                $hash = unserialize(file_get_contents("http://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/$video.php"));
        ?><img src="<?= $hash[0]['thumbnail_medium'] ?>" onclick="openvideo(<?= $video ?>)"><?php
            }
        ?>
        </div>
        <span id="prev"><</span>
        <span id="next">></span>
        </div><!-- thumbs -->
```

And script, its create thumbs

```
<script>
            function openvideo(video)
            {
            document.querySelector("iframe").src = "https://player.vimeo.com/video/" + video;
            }
        </script>

        <script>
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll(".thumbs div"), function($div)
                         {
                             $div.style.width = document.querySelectorAll(" img").length * 100 / 4 + "px";
                         });
document.querySelector("#next").onclick = function()
{
var i = 100;
var intervalId = setInterval(function()
            {
                document.querySelector(".thumbs").scrollLeft += 1;
                if(i == 0)
                {
                    clearInterval(intervalId);
                }
                i--;
            });
};
document.querySelector("#prev").onclick = function()
{
var i = 100;
var intervalId = setInterval(function()
            {
                document.querySelector(".thumbs").scrollLeft -= 1;
                if(i == 0)
                {
                    clearInterval(intervalId);
                }
                i--;
            });
};
        </script>
```

`$videos = Array("128171814",...` - its id video.
This is works fine when in `array` directly write ID's, but I want put ID's there from wordpress post editor.

Site in Wordpress, I created Custom Post Type where in editor put `"128171814", "128171814", "128171814",` and I want to show that in array()

Code now is look like

```
<? $args = array(
'post_type' => 'video-gallery',
    );?>

    <?php query_posts($args); ?>

    <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>

    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

        <?php
        $videocontent = get_the_content();
            $videos = Array($videocontent);
        ?>

.....ALL CODE .....

<?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; ?> 
    <?php wp_reset_query()  ?>
```

But now the link in `iframe` looks like

```
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/" 128171814",="" "128171814",="" "128171814","=""></iframe>
```

Show me the right way please. 
And sorry for my bad English.
Thank you.

Comment: Can you `var_dump($videos)` right after `$videos = Array($videocontent);` and see if the array has expected value?

Comment: Looking at your iframe link I think thats exactly where the issue is. It looks like `get_the_content()` is returning you a string with comma separated values. Can you show us what its returning `var_dump($videos)`?

Comment: `var_dump($videos)` returns `array(1) { [0]=> string(51) ""128171814", "128171814", "128171814", "128171814"," }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following bit has the issue. Function `get_the_content()` returns comma seperate values string. So you need to split it by comma and create the array.

```
$videocontent = get_the_content(); // Outputs: string(51) ""128171814", "128171814", "128171814", "128171814"
$videos = Array($videocontent);
```

So change the above bit by this:

```
$videocontent = get_the_content();
// Spit the comma separated values
$videos = explode(',', trim($videocontent, ','));

// Trim out the spaces and double quote
foreach($videos as $key => $val) {
    $videos[$key] = trim($val, ' "');
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Its work partly. There is another error  `Warning: file_get_contents(http://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/.php) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: Unable to find the socket transport "ssl" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? in Z:\home\narek.loc\www\wp-content\themes\narek\index.php on line 235`  here is var_dump result `array(4) { [0]=> string(11) ""128171814"" [1]=> string(12) " "128171814"" [2]=> string(12) " "128171814"" [3]=> string(0) "" }`

Comment: Also looking at your var_dump() I see an empty entry there. That will have to be stripped off from the array. I will edit my answer to address that.

Comment: @CroaToa I have updated my answer to take care of empty entry in the `$videos` Can you update your code and re-check?